# GROUP BY Nested Table Oracle DB 19 Error ORA-00932

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle19c

I have a Data

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE type TST_OBJ force
                   as table of varchar2(128)
```

And a table APPS that has a column 'Tst' of TST_OBJ type, as follows:

| Column_Name | Type of data |
| --- | --- |
| Name | varchar |
| Tst | TST_OBJ |
| Offs | number |

The issue comes when I try to SELECT and Group By the results as shown next:

```
select Tst, Offs from APPS group by Tst;
```

I'm getting error ORA-00932:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got TST_OBJ
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Is it possible that Group By does not work with this Type of Data or is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Can you show us how you created the table, best with the CREATE TABLE statement? Then we can try to reproduce the error you're getting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) says:

> Restrictions on the GROUP BY Clause
>
> This clause is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - **You cannot specify** LOB columns, **nested tables**, or varrays **as part of expr.**
> - The expressions can be of any form except scalar subquery expressions.
> - If the group_by_clause references any object type columns, then the query will not be parallelized.

I guess bold part answers your question.

---

```
SQL> create or replace type TST_OBJ force
  2    as table of varchar2(128);
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> create table apps
  2    (name varchar2(20),
  3     tst  tst_obj,                  --> here it is
  4     offs number)
  5  nested table tst store as tst_obj_tab;

Table created.

SQL> insert into apps values ('Little', tst_obj('A'), 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into apps values ('Foot'  , tst_obj('A', 'B', 'C'), 2);

1 row created.
```

Queries:

```
SQL> select tst, offs
  2  from apps;

TST                                            OFFS
---------------------------------------- ----------
TST_OBJ('A')                                      1
TST_OBJ('A', 'B', 'C')                            2

SQL> select tst, offs, count(*)
  2  from apps
  3  group by tst, offs;
group by tst, offs
         *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got SCOTT.TST_OBJ


SQL>
```